# Ever since he was a child + PAST PERFECT/PAST SIMPLE

Tags: past-tense

Which one is correct? I have come across the two.

> 1 Ever since he was a child, he had wanted to return to the US.
>
> 2 Ever since he was a child, he wanted to return to the US.

I don't consider this one "Ever since he was a child, he has wanted to return to the US." it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first one is good. "Ever since" indicates a span of time that continues to and includes the time of the verb, and simple past can only be used with times that finished before the verb.

Sentence 1 is the past version of the sentence you give last with present perfect. The past of the present perfect is past perfect.